# Use jquery to change select option when checkbox cell is checked in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a html table, one column is checkbox, and another column is select option. When the checkbox is selected, I want to set the select option in the same row to be disabled, and when the checkbox is unselected, make the select option in the same row to be enabled.
The jsfiddle demo is here, please help
   http://jsfiddle.net/9zyvfzgs/1/

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(3) input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    $("table tr td:nth-child(2)").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>item</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="you-are-my-select">
                <option>item</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>item</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>item</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="you-are-my-select">
                <option>item</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // option #1
    //$this.closest('tr').find('select.you-are-my-select').prop('disabled', $this.is(':checked'));

    // option #2, if the select always placed (for example) in third column
    $this.closest('tr').find('> td:nth-child(3) select').prop('disabled', $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

**jsfiddle link updated**

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/znp0f1mh/1/)

Comment: Thank you. I have several select in every row, can I specify the column index   like $this.closest('tr').children(':eq(1)').prop('disabled', $this.is(':checked')); ? The above children does not work. Sorry I'm new to JQuery.

Comment: For finding specific element (in your case, select), you need to add `class` or `id`, then use that to target the element. could you add `class` or `id` to the `select`?

Comment: Yes, after add class to the select, I can get it by $this.closest('tr').find('.mySelect').prop('disabled', $this.is(':checked')); Thank you